# Magento 2.2 and multiple currencies with fixed prices

Tags: magento, magento2.2

Site requirement is that all products are available to purchase in either GBP, USD or EUR. However, pricing is fixed for each product - client does not want pricing based on current exchange rates. If they did it'd be easy!

We have customers assigned to groups (price bands) and for each product we set the price for each price band. GBP has 5 price bands, USD has 2 and EUR has 1.

This is where it gets tricky. With the main site base currency set to GBP, in order to set USD & EUR in advanced pricing (i.e. fixed by customer group), we have to create a US and EU website. It's the only way to select a different currency in Advanced Pricing. Fine, but we don't want different domain/URLs for the three sites. That would in effect duplicate the same site three times with the only difference being the currency symbol. That would play havoc with search engine ranking. So I've set all three sites with the same domain but it doesn't work.

The only way to select the website when creating a customer is to have Account Sharing Options set to "per website"; otherwise the option to select website is disabled. I create a customer in admin, assigned to say the US site. Customer get's a mail to set password. Follow the link and try to set the password and it comes up with an error "Something went wrong while saving the new password." I'm guessing this is because it's trying to set the account password on the main site when the customer is associated with the US site. I've tried this multiple times and it's always the same error.

Anyone have any idea how to configure Magento 2.2 to support multiple currencies where pricing is fixed in Advanced Pricing by Customer Group and without having three duplicate public sites?